# How can I merge these two redux actions to one?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two form fields a and b. I need to dispatch a common action for both cases but should update the store accordingly.

```
switch (action.type) {
    case actions.ONINIT_a:
      return {
        ...state,
        parent: {
          ...state.parent,
          a: {
            ...state.parent.a,
            ...action.data
          }
        }
      };
    case actions.ONINIT_b:
      return {
        ...state,
        parent: {
          ...state.parent,
          b: {
            ...state.parent.b,
            ...action.data
          }
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a more general action that sends the parent as part of the action

```
const initParent = (data, parent) => ({
  type: ON_INIT,
  data,
  parent
});
```

Then you can generalize the reducer

```
switch (action.type) {
  case actions.ON_INIT:
    return {
      ...state,
      parent: {
        ...state.parent,
        [action.parent]: {
          ...state.parent[action.parent],
          ...action.data,
        }
      }
    };

    default:
      return state;
    }
};
```

**DEMO**

```js
const actions = {
  ON_INIT: 'ON_INIT',
};

const initParent = (data, parent) => ({
  type: actions.ON_INIT,
  data,
  parent
});

const initialState = {
  parent: {},
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.ON_INIT:
      return {
        ...state,
        parent: {
          ...state.parent,
          [action.parent]: {
            ...state.parent[action.parent],
            ...action.data,
          }
        }
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

let nextState;

nextState = reducer(initialState, initParent({ test: "data - a" }, "a"));
console.log("Update 1:", nextState);

nextState = reducer(nextState, initParent({ test: "data - b" }, "b"));
console.log("Update 2:", nextState);

nextState = reducer(nextState, initParent({ test: "new data - a" }, "a"));
console.log("Update 3:", nextState);
```

Comment: thanks I did something similar... ```case actions.ON_INIT:
      return {
        ...state,
        parent: {
          ...state.parent,
          [action.data.key]: {
            ...state.parent[action.data.key],
            ...action.data.value
          }
        }
      };```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-batch-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-batch-middleware) and dispatch multiple actions at once like this:

```
dispatch([{ type: actions.ONINIT_a }, { type: actions.ONINIT_b }])
```

Or write your own redux middleware for achieving the same.